# how to read/recover a udf partition

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, data-recovery, udf

I need to recover the files inside a UDF partition on my vcr external disk. Which program can I use in (preferably) Windows or Linux os?

Answer (score 1):

I have used [DiskInternals](http://www.diskinternals.com/cd-dvd-recovery/) to recover files from a UDF partition before

Comment: Thanks, but that program is unable to work on external usb disks.

Comment: Hard drive or flash?  If it's a hard drive in an external case, crack the case and stick it on an internal connector.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), from the people who made TestDisk. It's available on both Windows and Linux, but is a "command line GUI" program. If you're using Linux, the "command line" part doesn't matter anyways though...

Answer (score 1):

Modern versions of both Windows and Linux have native UDF filesystem support, so your device should
automatically be recognized and readable when plugged in. If this is not the case, perhaps you're
missing a hardware driver for the device your disk in on?